# I want to draw a graph with type "QGraphicsView" on a window with type "QWidget"

Tags: python, qt, plot, pyqt, pyside6

I have an application with a window with the type "QWidget" like this.

```
from sys import exit, argv
from PyQt6.QtCore import QRectF, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt6.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QMouseEvent, QPainter, QPen, QPaintEvent
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGraphicsView
from PyQt6.QtGui import QVector2D

targetPoint = QVector2D(1920/2, 120)
startPoint = QVector2D(1920/2, 1080 - 120)
barriers = {1:[690, 1080/2-30, 540, 60],
            2:[0-30, 0-30, 1920+60, 0+60],
            3:[0-30, 1080-30, 1920+60, 0+60],
            4:[0-30, 0+30, 0+60, 1080-60],
            5:[1920-30, 0+30, 0+60, 1080-60]}

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.framePerSecond = 60
        self.seconds = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.hours = 0
        self.clockCounterVariable = 0
        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Drawing Tutorial")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(20, 20, 20);font-size:20px;")
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.baseTimer = QTimer(self)
        self.baseTimer.timeout.connect(self.run)
        self.baseTimer.start(round((1/self.framePerSecond)*1000))
        self.clock = QTimer(self)
        self.clock.timeout.connect(self.clockCounter)
        self.clock.start(1000)

    def clockCounter(self) -> None:
        self.clockCounterVariable += 1

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, a0: QMouseEvent) -> super:
        global running
        if running:
            print("pause process")
            running = False
            self.baseTimer.stop()
            self.clock.stop()
        else:
            print("continue process")
            running = True
            self.baseTimer.start(10)
            self.clock.start(1000)
        return super().mousePressEvent(a0)

    def paintEvent(self, a0: QPaintEvent) -> super:
        self.painter.begin(self)
        self.painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(20, 20, 20), -1, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
        self.painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(80, 80, 80), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        for barrier in barriers:
            self.painter.drawRect(QRectF(barriers[barrier][0], barriers[barrier][1], barriers[barrier][2], barriers[barrier][3]))
        self.painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(30, 30, 30),  0, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
        self.painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(20, 20, 20),  -1, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
        self.painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(150, 30, 150), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        self.painter.drawEllipse(int(startPoint.x()-12), int(startPoint.y()-12), int(24), int(24))
        self.painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(150, 0, 0), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        self.painter.drawEllipse(int(targetPoint.x()-12), int(targetPoint.y()-12), int(24), int(24))
        self.painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 128, 0), 1, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
        self.seconds = self.clockCounterVariable
        self.minutes, self.seconds = divmod(self.seconds, 60)
        self.hours, self.minutes = divmod(self.minutes, 60)
        self.painter.drawText(QRectF(35, 30, 400, 30), Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft, "%02d : %02d : %02d" % (self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds))
        self.painter.end()
        return super().paintEvent(a0)

    def closeWindow(self) -> None:
        print("closing window ...")
        exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(argv)
    window = Window()
    try:
        exit(App.exec())
    except SystemExit:
        window.closeWindow()
```

that shows something like this.

[image]

I want to draw a graph at the right-bottom corner of this with 400px width and 300px height
I know I must use "QGraphicsView" but how can I show it? how to plot it?

I want to draw a graph with type "QGraphicsView" on a window with type "QWidget".

How should I do that?

Comment: You could create the Graphics View with Window as parent (`self.view = QGraphicsView(self)`), then override the `resizeEvent()` in order to always position it in the bottom right corner.

Comment: thank you so much I did (`self.view = QGraphicsView(self)`) then use (`setGeometry(1520, 780, 400, 300)`) to position it for a 1920x1080 display